# SpeechRecognizer returns results much slower after updating Google Search to 5.14.32.16.arm

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I was working on SpeechRecognizer with Google Search version 3.6.14.1337016 installed (on Android 4.4.2), with 2 languages `en-US` and `zh_HK`. I recently updated the Google Search (renamed to Google App) to version 5.14.32.16.arm, the speed of returning result is **slow** (takes around 35 seconds). Here is my code:

```
speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new CustomListener());
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "zh_HK");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "zh_HK");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, !isOnline());
intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.EXTRA_ADDITIONAL_LANGUAGES", new String[]{"zh_HK", "en-US"});
speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
```

where `CustomListener()` catches `onError` and `onResults`, and `isOnline()` detects whether network is available or not.

Before updating Google Search, the results are returned within 3 seconds. Here is the timeline after updating:

```
18:42:05.183 - onReadyForSpeech
18:42:05.513 - onBeginningOfSpeech
18:42:10.208 - onEndOfSpeech
18:42:45.663 - onResults
```

How to speed up the result retrieval?

Also, since I included `zh_HK`, the results included Chinese characters. However, space is added after each of the characters.

Before Update:

```
hello 你好嗎
```

After Update:

```
hello 你 好 嗎
```

Is this a known bug?

---

Extra findings:

If I uninstalled all Offline speech recognition languages, the `SpeechRecognizer` will 90% chance return `SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK`, while there is a small chance that the results return normally. How does that relate? I checked the device is online.

Comment: I got the same problem. Compared with RecognizerIntent, SpeechRecognizer is very slow in returning the results.